# How to move google bar chart to upper region?

Tags: python, google-visualization

I create a google bar chart.

However, the bar chart appeared in a very low region of the page.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Link:
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=17ZymcQdNuAH2oAvmtvHP3n5SjfMlOeik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you link to the `options` passed to `chart.draw(view, options);` in clude the value 6000 for the height. This is making the chart very tall and as a result the upper margin is also very tall.

If you decide that you need to keep the chart this tall then you can add to the options `chartArea: {'height': '90%'},` to increase the area the chart uses compared to the title and margin.

```
var options = {
    //option information
    title: "Daily number",
    width: 3000,
    height: 6000,
    chartArea: {'height': '90%'},
    bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
};
```